# Entering in data (User Name & Password)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the problem:
For example if I enter in "A" as the user name and "A" as the password, then click add user nothing happens. But if I go back in and now type "B" for the user name and "B" for that password and click add user it adds the previous entry "A" & "A" into the table. Like it's one behind?

I know I have something out of place.

```
    public partial class frmManageUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnAddUser_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                //string userName, userPassword;



        if (txtUserName.Text == "" || txtUserName.Text == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = ("User Name may not be empty");
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            return;
        }
       // else

           // userName = (txtUserName.Text);


        if (txtPassword.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = ("Password may not be empty");
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            return;
        }
        //else
           // userPassword = (txtPassword.Text);

        //using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString"))
        OleDbConnection conn =  
    new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            {

                string insert = "Insert INTO tblUserLogin (UserName, UserPassword, SecurityLevel) Values (@UserName, @UserPassword, @SecurityLevel)";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insert, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", txtPassword.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecurityLevel", drpdwnlstSecurityLevel.SelectedValue);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
            }

        Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
        Session["Password"] = txtPassword.Text;
        Session["SecurityLevel"] = drpdwnlstSecurityLevel.SelectedValue;
        Server.Transfer("frmManageUsers.aspx");

        //Server.Transfer("grdUserLogin"); 

    }
    protected void drpdwnlstSecurityLevel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use Server.Transfer to get to the page the first time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to be missing a conn.Close().  That would cause the delay in writing to the table.  Also, consider putting your conn in a using statement to properly dispose of the object.